# Submenu positioning in Wordpress dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a WordPress site, running the default 2017 theme, that I've modified with a lot of custom CSS.

My last big problem is that I can't get the submenu positioned correctly. When clicking on the hamburger menu in the top right, the submenu, which is formatted to left-align with the hamburger menu, shifts off the screen for mobile devices.

I need to shorten the submenu block widths to match the text length, and then right-align those blocks to the edge of the screen.

It's probably easier to just look at the site to see what I mean:
[www.indivisiblesaz.org](http://www.indivisiblesaz.org) (sorry, it's a political site.)

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on your website, seems to work.

```
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul, .main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
    left: -2.5em;
    right: auto;
}
```

And you can also adjust width in the following part:

```
.main-navigation ul ul a {
    padding: 0.75em 1.25em;
    width: 190px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.